# Is there an efficient way to use ffmpeg to perform a large quantity of cuts from a single file?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python, nvenc

I'm trying to cut video files into smaller chunks. (each one being one word said in the video, so they're not all of equal size)

I've tried a lot of different approaches to try to be as efficient as possible, but I can't get the runtime to be under 2/3rd of the original video length. That's an issue because I'm trying to process 400+ hours of video.

Is there a more efficient way to do this ? Or am I doomed to run this for weeks ?

Here is the command for my best attempt so far

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -ss start_timestamp -t to_timestamp -i file_name -vf "fps=30,scale_cuda=1280:720" -c:v h264_nvenc -y output_file
```

Note that the machine running the code has a 4090
This command is then executed via python, which gives it the right timestamps and file paths for each smaller clip in a for loop

I think it's wasting a lot of time calling a new process each time, however I haven't been able to get better results with a split filter; but here's the ffmpeg-python code for that attempt:

Creation of the stream:

```
inp = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(file_name, hwaccel="cuda", hwaccel_output_format="cuda")
    .filter("fps",fps=30)
    .filter('scale_cuda', '1280','720')
    .filter_multi_output('split')
)
```

Which then gets called in a for loop

```
(
    ffmpeg
    .filter(inp, 'trim', start=row[1]['start'], end=row[1]['end'])
    .filter('setpts', 'PTS-STARTPTS')
    .output(output_file,vcodec='h264_nvenc')
    .run()
)
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `trim`, see https://superuser.com/a/682534/363732

Answer (score 0):

Do you know all the trims before running ffmpeg? If so, my best bet is to use a complex filtergraph with a split filter and a bunch of the trim-setpts filter chains in parallel to generate multiple outputs in a single FFmpeg run.

This will eliminate time to spawn a new FFmpeg subprocess each time and to seek video each time. Also, FFmpeg may utilize more threads. That being said, remember that the most likely bottleneck is the storage access. So, that could be the reason for you not meeting your performance goal.

How long does it take to process the file from the beginning to the end while outputting to null? If this doesn't run in < 2/3 duration, no optimization will help. Also, just out of curiosity, have you benchmarked CPU/GPU filtering approaches to see which one is faster by how much?

Comment: I've also benchmarked cpu & gpu approaches, though the gpu is always either slightly (10%) or significantly (100%+) slower, I'm not sure why, i may be using the parameters wrong, but the fastest gpu results are witht he same cpu command with `-hwaccel cuda` added before the input

Comment: I did experiment with a complex filter graph, and it does give the best results so far (down to 1/3rd of the total length of video) here is the command 
`command = f'ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error  -i {input_filepath} '\               f'-filter_complex_script filter_complex.txt {maps}' `
`filter_complex += f"[0:v]trim=start={start_time}:end={end_time},setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[{output_filename}v];[0:a]atrim=start={start_time}:end={end_time},asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[{output_filename}a];"         maps += f"-map [{output_filename}v] -map [{output_filename}a] {output_filename} "`

Comment: These commands are generated with python code, and up to the 8000 chars limit, so for a typical 15min speech, 41 commands are generated in total

Comment: I ran the command while outputting to null, and i get the same speed as if i was writing to disk, note that I'm writing to a SSD rated for 6600 MBps max writing speed

Comment: Additional context on the cpu of the machine, it's using a 14900k, capped at 253W

Comment: [Re: 8000 char limit] you can put the filtergraph definition in a text file (or pipe it in directly from Python via stdin) to circumvent that limit

Comment: Check the resource meter to see CPU and storage utilization %. If storage bandwidth is not maxed out, consider spawning multiple ffmpeg subprocesses in parallel using `Popen`

Comment: Another benchmark idea: try the first 30 seconds and the last 30 seconds of the input video alone to see if there are any discrepancies in time it takes to process.

Comment: GPU may be slower if ffmpeg needs to copy the data back-n-forth between CPU & GPU memories

Comment: [Re: 8000 char limit] I'm already using a txt file for the filtergraph, however it's the maps that take up the 8k char limit, as far as i know we cant use a txt file for maps, right ?

Comment: Right. I'm afraid to ask how many files you're producing lol.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked the documentation, and I may have found a solution. see if [preset file](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Preset-files) would solve it

Comment: Its about 3k files for a 15 minutes video, but the goal is to be able to process 500+ hours of video eventually, which is why I want to optimize this as much as possible

Comment: [Re: CPU and storage utilization %], The disk (& RAM) use stays under 10%, while CPU quickly jumps to 60-80+, I've tried spawning multiple ffmpeg instances, but for some reason, it slows to a crawl after +-100s, and never finishes

Comment: [Re: first 30 seconds and the last] Interesting, the first 30s took 3.43s, and the last took 9.81s, i guess it means ffmpeg is decoding the entire video if it has to trim a clip at the end ?

Comment: [Re: preset file] I've looked into it, and I'm not sure how this can help here, do you mean using a preset file optimized for this task, or making one to avoid the 8k char limit ?